# String Pattern Matching In Java

Tags: java, string, matching

I want to search for a given string pattern in an input sting.

For Eg.

```
String URL = "https://localhost:8080/sbs/01.00/sip/dreamworks/v/01.00/cui/print/$fwVer/{$fwVer}/$lang/en/$model/{$model}/$region/us/$imageBg/{$imageBg}/$imageH/{$imageH}/$imageSz/{$imageSz}/$imageW/{$imageW}/movie/Kung_Fu_Panda_two/categories/3D_Pix/item/{item}/_back/2?$uniqueID={$uniqueID}"
```

Now I need to search whether the string URL contains "`/{item}/`". Please help me.

This is an example. Actually I need is check whether the URL contains a string matching "/{a-zA-Z0-9}/"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `Pattern` class for this. If you want to match only word characters inside the `{}` then you can use the following regex. `\w` is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you are ok with `_` then use `\w` or else use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

```
String URL = "https://localhost:8080/sbs/01.00/sip/dreamworks/v/01.00/cui/print/$fwVer/{$fwVer}/$lang/en/$model/{$model}/$region/us/$imageBg/{$imageBg}/$imageH/{$imageH}/$imageSz/{$imageSz}/$imageW/{$imageW}/movie/Kung_Fu_Panda_two/categories/3D_Pix/item/{item}/_back/2?$uniqueID={$uniqueID}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\{\\w+\\}/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); //prints /{item}/
} else {
    System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: what was the + for, when using \\w+ ?

Comment: @COLDICE `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more times.

Answer (score 14):

That's just a matter of [`String.contains`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if (input.contains("{item}"))
```

If you need to know *where* it occurs, you can use `indexOf`:

```
int index = input.indexOf("{item}");
if (index != -1) // -1 means "not found"
{
    ...
}
```

That's fine for matching *exact* strings - if you need real *patterns* (e.g. "three digits followed by at most 2 letters A-C") then you should look into [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like you *do* want regular expressions. You might want something like this:

```
private static final Pattern URL_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("/\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\}/");

...

if (URL_PATTERN.matcher(input).find())
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Now i edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: @1355: Okay, so that's completely changed the nature of the question... but it's not really clear what you mean. Please give some examples of URLs you do and don't want to match. Is it "any number of letters/digits, but they have to be in braces"?

Comment: I need to check this pattern "/{a-zA-Z0-9}/".  The pattern should include two slashes and two braces. But the letters can be anything.

Comment: For eg: "/{asdFs7f}/", "/{asdfg}/", "/{ASDF}/", "/{23445}/". Now I think you got what i meant. In that URL string there are many sub strings like "/{$asdf}/". It shouldn't match.

Comment: `.matcher()`. Not `.matches()`.

Comment: @Det: Fixed - feel free to just edit typos directly in future though.

Comment: @Det: Ironically it looks like I originally got it right, and a different user "corrected` it to `matches()` (while fixing a separate, genuine issue).

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know. I just don't like to edit other people's things.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if some string is present in another string, use something like  `String.contains`

If you want to check if some *pattern* is present in a string, append and prepend the pattern with '.*'. The result will accept strings that contain the pattern.

Example: Suppose you have some regex *a(b|c)* that checks if a string matches `ab` or `ac` 
`.*(a(b|c)).*` will check if a string contains a `ab` or `ac`.

A disadvantage of this method is that it will not give you the location of the match, you can use java.util.Mather.find() if you need the position of the match.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `string.indexOf("{item}")`. If the result is greater than -1 `{item}` is in the string

Comment: :Thanks for your immediate response. Now i edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: Jon already did it, so there is no need to repeat him. You need `Pattern` and optionally `Matcher.`