# java substring of string with OR option

Tags: java

Let say I have a list of strings like:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("person [something]");
myList.add("person 'something'");
```

so in my strings sometimes I have [ and sometimes '

and now I would like to get substrings but I don't know how to do this if I would like to cut my string in one of the two chars.
Can anyone tell me whether that option is possible?
I tried something like:

```
List finalOne = new ArrayList();
for(String ss: myList){
finalOne.add(ss.substring("[" || "'" ))

}
```

I expect to get all substrings starting from char "[" or starting from  "'" in one run

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: use something like `indexOf` to find out which char is present or use a regex to split correctly.

Comment: `substring` doesn't work this way (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])` and `(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')` regular expressions to find the string between square brackets and single quotes.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938033/string-pattern-matching-in-java), for searching pattern in java, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud), for the regular expression.

Comment: I need further help  :(
I did something like that in java

String regex = "(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=\\])";
String string = "sdsds [test] fdfddf";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = matcher.pattern(string)
log.info(matcher.group(0));

but I get 
NO MATCHERS

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You might wanna post another question